# Write vertical text using Direct2D's DirectWrite

Tags: c#, direct2d

I want to write vertical text like it is known from a simple chart's y-axis. I found the FlowDirection property which allows me to add the "ToptoBottom" direction but this does not change the text's behaviour.

Is it the only way to rotate the rendertarget by 90 degress, write the text and rotate it back? The problem here is that I also have to recalculate the points for the rotation matrix.

This seems a lot of work just for rotating text? Any better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not in front of my computer right now so bear with me. When you are creating the text format you can set the width of the bounding box of the text to the text font size and it should only write one letter per line, giving you vertical text effect that you want!

Comment: That's great. Is there a solution also to rotate text for 90 degrees?

Comment: go here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj218764(v=vs.85).aspx

You should be dealing with: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh780432(v=vs.85).aspx